# What has to be done to resolve 80040154 Class not registered execption

Tags: c#, sap-gui

I am facing the following error only when i try to run the project on a target machine

> [ERROR] ExecuteTestScriptsOnSAP_GUI: Retrieving the COM class factory
>   for compo   nent with CLSID {B90F32AD-859E-4EDD-BFAE-C9216849520C}
>   failed due to the foll   owing error: 80040154 Class not registered
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004015   4 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

It seems to work fine on my development machine.

I am trying to launch `SAP gui 7.40` from my project and it has a reference to `Interop.SAPFEWSELib.dll`

The above `.dll` file was built when `sapfewse.ocx` was first added as a dependency to the project.

Can anyone please guide me as to what can be done to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet and so can only respond in an answer.

It could be that that the control sapfewse.ocx that you are consuming via Interop.SAPFEWSELib.dll is not registered on your target machine.

Check the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID  and locate the class for B90F32AD-859E-4EDD-BFAE-C9216849520C on your dev machine. The InProcServer32 key should tell you the path of the registered component. Ensure that this component is deployed and registered on your target machine.

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: I checked the registry path . Regsitry folder InProcServer32 has a key 'Default' with 'c:\program files (x86)\sap\frontend\sapgui\sapfewse.ocx' value.
How do i register this component on my dev machine?

Comment: I was not able to comment due to being new and insufficient rep. I can now comment and so will do in future. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a 32bit OS machine then

"C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe" /i "Path to OCX"

Or 64 bit then "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe"

If you double click the .ocx on the target machine, it should prompt you to select a program to complete the action with. Browse to the relevant regsvr32.exe and it will then register it for you.

But it looks as if your ocx comes from a third party SDK? as it resides in c:\program files (x86)\sap\frontend\sapgui\ on your dev machine. Have you installed this SDK on your target machine? If not.. do so and this will install and register the component for you.